# Is there a way to get all keys inside of an object (including sub-objects)?

Tags: javascript, object

Currently, I'm trying to get all the keys of an object, including the sub-objects.

I know that

```js
Object.keys(obj)
```

returns the keys of the object, but not the keys of the objects inside of it.

So, for example, I got following object:

```js
let exampleObject = 
{
   a: "value",
   b: "value",
   c: 404,
   d: {
      e: "value",
      f: "value"
   }
}
```

**NOTE:** The **d** key might change its name, so it won't work to use something like *Object.keys(obj.d)*.

How do I get *e* and *f* in my total list of keys existing inside an object?

Comment: You also want `d` in result or not?

Comment: @MaheerAli Yes, I also want `d` inside.

Comment: The accepted answer at the link DCR suggested should do it. If you know you only need two levels deep, you can skip the recursion and just add one conditional `Object.keys(prop)` (or something similar) for when `typeof prop == Object`.
And if you want to avoid getting the keys of nested arrays, you can further specify `&& !Array.isArray(prop)` (or something similar).

Comment: @Cat After looking inside, I also think that it is what I searched for. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatmap) to recursively get the keys like this:

```js
let exampleObject={a:"value",b:"value",c:404,d:{e:"value",f:"value"}};

const getKeys = obj => Object.keys(obj).flatMap(k => Object(obj[k]) === obj[k] 
                                                        ? [k, ...getKeys(obj[k])] 
                                                        : k)

console.log(getKeys(exampleObject))
```

If `flatMap` is not supported, use `reduce` like this:

```
function getKeys(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((r, k) => {
    r.push(k);

    if(Object(obj[k]) === obj[k])
      r.push(...getKeys(obj[k]));

    return r;
  }, [])
}
```

The `Object(obj[k]) === obj[k]` checks if the property is an object and it is not `null`. Because, `typeof null === "object"`

Comment: flatMap should make this easy (IF you can count on browser support for it).

Comment: @Cat It would be just a Node.js application running on a server without any frontend so browser support is (in my case) unnecessary.

Comment: @Cat we should stop worrying about browser support and leave it to the build tools like webpack that can automatically provide exact polyfills for the specified list of browsers our audience is using

Answer (score 2):

You can try that using recursion.

- Create a wrapper function `getAllKeys()` and create an empty array inside that.
- Now create another function `getKeys()` which takes object and which will be called recursively.
- Inside `getKeys()` loop through the keys using `for..in`.
- `push()` the key into empty array created in wrapper function.
- Check if the `typeof` key is `"object"` then call the function recursively on that.

```js
let exampleObject = 
{
   a: "value",
   b: "value",
   c: 404,
   d: {
      e: "value",
      f: "value"
   }
}

function getAllKeys(obj){
  let res = []
  function getKeys(obj){
    for(let key in obj){
      res.push(key);
      if(typeof obj[key] === "object"){
        getKeys(obj[key])
      }
      
    }
  }
  getKeys(obj);
  return res;
}
console.log(getAllKeys(exampleObject))
```